# Dynamically set local variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, local-variables

I'm interested in dynamically setting local variables in Ruby.  Not creating methods, constants, or instance variables.

So something like:

```
args[:a] = 1
args.each_pair do |k,v|
  Object.make_instance_var k,v
end
puts a
> 1
```

I want locally variables specifically because the method in question lives in a model and I dont want to pollute the global or object space.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need local variables instead of simply accessing the pairs in `args`?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a bunch of variable names and values in method X which are then to be used in method Y as variables local to method Y ? Also, here is a useful comment from matz: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/155673#685906

Comment: Basically I have a set of functions with nebulous parameters, and it would be a lot clearer to pass in:  present_value(:n=>6,:m=>4..etc), and then use them in the function as local variables automatically instead of reduplicating myself by redefining them or using them in hash form.  Along the lines of your comment Zabba I looked at: https://github.com/maca/arguments ...but couldnt get it to work reliably in 1.9.2 since its apparently no longer under active development.

Comment: Hehe, it doesn't work for 1.9.2, we lost the facitilities for extracting s trees from live objects. you could do crazy stuff with that. I am the author

Comment: Ruby 2.2.2 may add the ability to add this via binding.local_variables

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem here is that the block inside each_pair has a different scope.  Any local variables assigned therein will only be accessible therein.  For instance, this:

```
args = {}
args[:a] = 1
args[:b] = 2

args.each_pair do |k,v|
  key = k.to_s
  eval('key = v')
  eval('puts key')
end

puts a
```

Produces this:

```
1
2
undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object (NameError)
```

In order to get around this, you could create a local hash, assign keys to this hash, and access them there, like so:

```
args = {}
args[:a] = 1
args[:b] = 2

localHash = {}
args.each_pair do |k,v|
  key = k.to_s
  localHash[key] = v
end

puts localHash['a']
puts localHash['b']
```

Of course, in this example, it's merely copying the original hash with strings for keys.  I'm assuming that the actual use-case, though, is more complex.

Comment: You're correct.  Essentially I want a painless way to pass named arguments, and then use them in the method.  Too bad the eval trick doesn't get it, I imagine any option would have miserable performance anyway.

Comment: key = k.to_s
 followed by 
  eval('key = v')
  does not have the effect you expect,
key = 1234  has the same effect

Comment: `eval` is not ideal because not everything can be easily serialized to string

Answer (score 29):

As an additional information for future readers, starting from ruby 2.1.0 you can using `binding.local_variable_get` and `binding.local_variable_set`:

```
def foo
  a = 1
  b = binding
  b.local_variable_set(:a, 2) # set existing local variable `a'
  b.local_variable_set(:c, 3) # create new local variable `c'
                              # `c' exists only in binding.
  b.local_variable_get(:a) #=> 2
  b.local_variable_get(:c) #=> 3
  p a #=> 2
  p c #=> NameError
end
```

As stated in [the doc](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set), it is a similar behavior to

```
binding.eval("#{symbol} = #{obj}")
binding.eval("#{symbol}")
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work as-is, because `b.local_variable_set(:b, 3)` overwrites the binding you previously stored in `b`. Storing the binding in a different variable fixes the problem.

Comment: @Kelvin thanks, I fixed it

Answer (score 10):

interesting, you can **change** a local variable but you cannot **set** it:

```
def test
  x=3
  eval('x=7;')
  puts x
end
```

test => 
7

```
def test
  eval('x=7;')
  puts x
end
```

test => 
NameError: undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object

This is the only reason why Dorkus Prime's code works.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you use the hash (but keep reading for other alternatives).

**Why?**

Allowing arbitrary named arguments makes for extremely unstable code.

Let's say you have a method `foo` that you want to accept these theoretical named arguments.

Scenarios:

1. The called method (`foo`) needs to call a private method (let's call it `bar`) that takes no arguments. If you pass an argument to `foo` that you wanted to be stored in local variable `bar`, it will mask the `bar` method. The workaround is to have explicit parentheses when calling `bar`.
2. Let's say `foo`'s code assigns a local variable. But then the caller decides to pass in an arg with the same name as that local variable. The assign will clobber the argument.

Basically, a method's caller must never be able to alter the logic of the method.

**Alternatives**

An alternate middle ground involves `OpenStruct`. It's less typing than using a hash.

```
require 'ostruct'
os = OpenStruct.new(:a => 1, :b => 2)
os.a  # => 1
os.a = 2  # settable
os.foo  # => nil
```

Note that `OpenStruct` allows you access non-existent members - it'll return `nil`. If you want a stricter version, use `Struct` instead.

This creates an anonymous class, then instantiates the class.

```
h = {:a=>1, :b=>2}
obj = Struct.new(* h.keys).new(* h.values)
obj.a  # => 1
obj.a = 2  # settable
obj.foo  # NoMethodError
```

Answer (score 1):

since you don't want constants

```
args = {}
args[:a] = 1
args[:b] = 2

args.each_pair{|k,v|eval "@#{k}=#{v};"}

puts @b
```

2

you might find this approach interesting ( evaluate the variables in the right context)

```
fn="b*b"
vars=""
args.each_pair{|k,v|vars+="#{k}=#{v};"}
eval vars + fn
```

4

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but OP says instance variables are not acceptable. Which is reasonable, because that will alter the state of the object.