# Name Instance Variables Dynamically Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, dynamic, naming

What I want to do is name variables dynamically like:

```
def instance(instance)
    @instance = instance #@instance isn't actually a variable called @instance, rather a variable called @whatever was passed as an argument
end
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set local variables in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963678/dynamically-set-local-variables-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really.

You could play around with `eval`, but really, it won't be readable.

Use the correct `if` or use a hash instead.

```
# With Hash:
values = {}
a = :foo
values[a] = "bar"
values[:foo] # => "bar"

# With if
calc = "bar"
if a_is_foo
  foo = calc
else
  oof = calc
end
foo # => "bar"
```

Comment: how? what exactly do you mean?

Comment: He means: `var = :a; hash = { var => 'foo' }; hash[var] = 'bar'; hash[var];`

Comment: I would never suggest the use of `eval` for this.  It's a design flaw and eval is dangerous in the wrong hands ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use `instance_variable_set`.

```
varname = '@foo'
value = 'bar'
self.instance_variable_set varname, value
@foo   # => "bar"
```

Or if you don't want the caller to have to supply the '@':

```
varname = 'foo'
value = 'bar'
self.instance_variable_set "@#{varname}", value
@foo   # => "bar"
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you want to use "instance_variable_set":

```
class A
end

a = A.new
a.instance_variable_set("@whatever", "foo")

a.instance_variable_get("@whatever") #=> "foo"
```