# Ruby turn values inside a hash into local variables

Tags: ruby

Say I have this hash:

```
entry = {"director"=>"Chris Nolan", "producer"=>"Sum Duk", "writer"=>"Saad Bakk"}
```

I want to extract each key into its own local variable with the associated value:

```
director = "Chris Nolan"
producer = "Sum Duk"
...
```

By using a loop and not:

```
director = entry["director"]
```

Since there are a lot of values and I don't want to do them individually.

I found this which works almost perfectly except it creates an instance variable and I want a local variable, but `local_variable_set` doesn't exist for some reason.

```
entry.each_pair { |k, v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) }
```

Is there a solution? Or failing that, a way to turn an instance variable into a local one and delete the instance one without doing it one by one?

Comment: Any reason they can't stay in the hash and be accessed from there? Presumably, you're using the local variables later - wouldn't it be just as easy to use the hash values?

Comment: If you're using Rails (or just ActiveSupport), you can use the following one-liner: `director, producer, writer = entry.values_at('director', 'producer', 'writer')`. It's unfortunate that you have to type each variable name twice (instead of zero times as you asked for), but it is still the most concise way I've found to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically create a local variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552891/how-to-dynamically-create-a-local-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create local variables, because of variable scope.
If you create a local variable inside a block, the variable would be only accessible inside the block itself.
Please refer to this question for more info.
[Dynamically set local variables in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963678/dynamically-set-local-variables-in-ruby)

Comment: That makes sense, but is very sad. I guess I'm stuck using instance variables or doing it manually :(

Comment: Indeed it is. I guess sacrificing some lines in the code is the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

**Option 1**

I can't recommend this except for fun, but it mostly has the effect you are after:

```
entry.each |k, v|
  singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, k)
  send("#{k}=", v)
end

director                        # => "Chris Nolan"
self.director = "Wes Anderson"  # Unfortunately, must use self for assignment
director                        # => "Wes Anderson"
```

Instead of creating local variables it defines acccessor methods on the singleton class of the current object, which you can call as if they were local variables.

To make them more "local" you could use `singleton_class.remove_method` to remove these methods when you are done with them.  You could even try to alias any existing singleton class methods with the same name and restore them afterwards.

**Option 2**

This is something I use in real code. It requires the ActiveSupport gem which comes with Ruby On Rails but can also be used on its own.

```
director, producer, writer = entry.values_at('director', 'producer', 'writer')
```

Unfortunately it requires typing each variable name twice, instead of zero times as you asked for. If you were certain about the order of the values in the hash, you could write:

```
director, producer, writer = entry.values  # Not so good, IMO.
```

I feel uneasy about this version because now the code that created the hash has a non-obvious responsibility to ensure the hash is in a certain order.

**Note**

If your goal is just to reduce typing, here is an approach that only requires two more characters per variable access than if they were true local variables:

```
e = OpenStruct.new(entry)
e.director     # => "Chris Nolan"
```

Comment: Option 2 – `values_at` – is a great option .

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `eval`, but all operations on those variables must be inside the scope they were defined in.

For example, this will work:

```
vals = {
  "foo" => "bar",
  "baz" => "qux"
}

eval <<-EOF
  #{ vals.map {|k, v| "#{k} = \"#{v}\""}.join("\n") }
  puts foo
EOF
```

However, this will not:

```
vals = {
  "foo" => "bar",
  "baz" => "qux"
}

eval <<-EOF
  #{ vals.map {|k, v| "#{k} = \"#{v}\""}.join("\n") }
EOF

puts foo
```

as `foo` goes out of scope at the end of the eval. However, if all your work on the variables can be done inside the scope of the eval, it's quite doable.

Comment: @kakubei: Exactly, in Ruby you can break through almost any constraint. Although the one you chose - local variables - is a bit difficult, local variables are only meant for small time use.

Comment: That doesn't really work for hashes with non-string (or stringable) keys.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @antinome's note: If you want local variables just to exist, because you want to access them dynamically for instance by interpolating them in a String, then `OpenStruct` + `instance_eval` offers this powerful way:

```
require 'ostruct'
o = OpenStruct.new(entry)
o.instance_eval("Directed by #{director}, produced by #{producer}")
o.instance_eval {
  puts "Directed by #{director}"
  puts "Produced by #{producer}"
}
```

Comment: I would prefer `instance_exec` over `instance_eval`

Comment: @NickRoz Why would it matter in general and in this case?

Comment: In that very case I guess there is no difference, but I stick to it as a general recommendation to avoid temptation to pass a string inside (just like in the 3rd line of code) from parameters / user intput / database, thus it is relatively easy to get code injection. Whereas _exec is limited to blocks only, that at least protects you from a mistake. Apart from this it is underestimated answer