# How to dynamically create a local variable?

Tags: ruby

I have a variable `var = "some_name"` and I would like to create a new object and assign it to `some_name`. How can I do it? E.g.

```
var = "some_name"
some_name = Struct.new(:name) # I need this
a = some_name.new('blah') # so that I can do this.
```

Comment: `"some_name"` and `some_name` is different,one is object and other is local variable..

Comment: true. I wanted to use the value of `var` as a left operand during Struct.new

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of things like Perl or PHP where `$x = 'y'` and `$$x = 'z'` means the same thing as `$y = 'z'`. There's no specific equivalent in Ruby, as variable references don't exist per-se.

Comment: Why not just store the variable in a hash?

`h = {} ; h[:some_name] = Stuct.new(:name) ; a = h[:some_name].new('blah')`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You cannot dynamically create local variables in Ruby 1.9+ (you could in Ruby 1.8 via [`eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-eval)):

```
eval 'foo = "bar"'
foo  # NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
```

They can be used within the eval-ed code itself, though:

```
eval 'foo = "bar"; foo + "baz"'
#=> "barbaz"
```

Ruby 2.1 added [`local_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set), but that cannot create new local variables either:

```
binding.local_variable_set :foo, 'bar'
foo # NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
```

This behavior *cannot* be changed without modifying Ruby itself. The alternative is to instead consider storing your data within another data structure, e.g. a Hash, instead of many local variables:

```
hash = {}
hash[:my_var] = :foo
```

---

Note that both `eval` and `local_variable_set` *do* allow reassigning an existing local variable:

```
foo = nil
eval 'foo = "bar"'
foo  #=> "bar"
binding.local_variable_set :foo, 'baz'
foo  #=> "baz"
```

Comment: Please read the last paragraph. If you think you need to dynamically create or read from variables, especially local variables, it's usually a sign that you're not using the correct data structures.

Comment: Ruby 2.1 introduced local_variable_set, local_variable_get, and local_variable_defined? on Binding

Comment: Technically you can create local variables, but they're local to the `eval` context. You just can't push them up to the parent context.

Comment: Thanks for the local_variable_set info !

Answer (score 5):

Speaking of ruby 2.2.x it is true that you can't create local variables programatically in current context/binding.. but you can set variables in some particular binding you have a handle of.

```
b = binding
b.local_variable_set :gaga, 5
b.eval "gaga"
=> 5
```

Interesting here is that calls to `binding` give you a new binding each time. So you need to get a handle of the binding you are interested in and then eval in it's context once desired variables are set.

How is this useful? For example I want to evaluate ERB and writing ERB is much nicer if you can use `<%= myvar %>` instead of `<%= opts[:myvar] %>` or something like that.

To create a new binding I'm using a module *class* method (I'm sure somebody will correct me how to call this properly, in java I'd call it a static method) to get a clean binding with particular variables set:

```
module M
  def self.clean_binding
    binding
  end

  def self.binding_from_hash(**vars)
    b = self.clean_binding
    vars.each do |k, v|
      b.local_variable_set k.to_sym, v
    end
    return b
  end
end
my_nice_binding = M.binding_from_hash(a: 5, **other_opts)
```

Now you have a binding with only the desired variables. You can use it for nicer controlled evaluation of ERB or other (possibly third party) **trusted** code (this is **not** a sandbox of any kind). It's like defining an interface.

update: A few additional notes about bindings. Place you create them also affects the availability of methods and Constants resolution. In the above example I create a reasonably clean binding. But if I want to make available the instance methods of some object, I could create a binding by a similar method but within the class of that object. e.g.

```
module MyRooTModule
  class Work
    def my_instance_method
      ...
    end
    def not_so_clean_binding
      binding
    end
  end
  class SomeOtherClass
  end
end
```

Now my `my_object.not_so_clean_binding` will allow code to call `#my_instance_method` on `my_object` object. In the same way, you can call for example `SomeOtherClass.new` in code using this binding instead of `MyRootModule::SomeOtherClass.new`. So there is sometimes more consideration needed when creating a binding than just local variables. HTH

Answer (score 3):

It is true what others wrote that you cannot dynamically declare *true* variable in a local context. However you can achieve similar functionality with **object attributes** and since in the Ruby world everything is an object (even main context) you can easily extend those objects with new attributes. Of corse, this operation can be done dynamically. Let's examine this approach.

Firstly, let's look at the main scope with `irb`.

```
> self
=> main
> self.class
=> Object
> self.class.ancestors
=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

As you can see now, `main` is truly an object. Objects can have attributes which have same [indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection)  property as variables. Normally, when declaring new class we would use `attr_accessor` method but `main` is already an instantiated object thus we cannot declare new attributes directly. Here **module mixins** come for rescue.

```
variable_name = 'foo'
variable_value = 'bar'

variable_module = Module.new do
  attr_accessor variable_name.to_sym
end

include variable_module

instance_variable_set("@#{variable_name}", variable_value)

p foo # "bar"

self.foo = 'bad'

p foo # "baz"

self.class.ancestors
# [Object, #<Module:0x007f86cc073aa0>, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Now you see that `main` object was tainted with new module that introduced new attribute `foo`. For further inspection you can run `methods` to see that `main` now have two more methods `foo` and `foo=`.

To simplify this operation I wrote [metaxa](https://github.com/mckomo/metaxa) gem which I highly encourage you to check out. This is example of how to use it.

```
require 'metaxa'

include Metaxa

introduce :foo, with_value: 'foo'

puts foo == 'foo' # true
puts foo === get(:foo) # true

set :foo, 'foobar'

puts foo == 'foobar' # true
puts foo === get(:foo) # true

self.foo = 'foobarbaz'

puts foo == 'foobarbaz' # true
puts foo === get(:foo) # true
```

Answer (score 2):

Although, as others have pointed out, you cannot dynamically create local variables in Ruby, you can simulate this behavior to some degree using methods:

```
hash_of_variables = {var1: "Value 1", var2: "Value 2"}

hash_of_variables.each do |var, val|
  define_method(var) do
    instance_variable_get("@__#{var}")
  end
  instance_variable_set("@__#{var}", val)
end

puts var1
puts var2
var1 = var2.upcase
puts var1
```

Prints:

```
Value 1
Value 2
VALUE 2
```

Some libraries combine this technique with `instance_exec` to expose what appear to be local variables inside a block:

```
def with_vars(vars_hash, &block)
  scope = Object.new
  vars_hash.each do |var, val|
    scope.send(:define_singleton_method, var) do
      scope.instance_variable_get("@__#{var}")
    end
    scope.instance_variable_set("@__#{var}", val)
  end
  scope.instance_exec(&block)
end

with_vars(a: 1, b:2) do
  puts a + b
end
```

Prints: 3

Be aware though that the abstraction is by no means perfect:

```
with_vars(a: 1, b:2) do
  a = a + 1
  puts a
end
```

Results in: `` undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass ``. This is because `a=` defines an actual local variable, initialized to `nil`, which takes precedence over the method `a`. Then `a.+(1)` gets called, and `nil` doesn't have a `+` method, so an error is thrown.

So while this method is pretty useful for simulating read-only local variables, it doesn't always work well when you try to reassign the variable inside the block.