# Ruby dynamically define arguments

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

What I basically want to achieve is:

```
arguments     = [:foo, :bar]
multiplicator = ->(_something_funky_with_arguments_) { foo * bar }
multiplicator.call(3, 4) # => 12
```

Is there a way to do that other than building the entire lambda as string and `eval`ing it?

```
eval("->(#{arguments.join(', ')}) { foo * bar }")
```

Comment: If I understood your question, it is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552891/how-to-dynamically-create-a-local-variable

Comment: As @Thomas suggests, to do this one needs to create local variables for the lambda's block variables, but local variables cannot be created in v1.9+; in v1.8 they can only be created by using `eval`.

Comment: Ruby can be hard if you want to use it like C++. You cannot use variables' name from scope A and reuse them in scope B meanwhile replacing their referenced value. Take a look at Lambda Calculus and Beta reduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
multiplicator = Proc.new {|*arguments| arguments.inject(&:*) }
multiplicator.call(3, 4) # => 12
multiplicator.call(3, 4, 5) # => 60
```

or if you prefer lambda syntax:

```
multiplicator = ->(*arguments) { arguments.inject(&:*) }
multiplicator.call(3, 4) # => 12
multiplicator.call(3, 4, 5) # => 60
```

---

After comments, maybe this is your solution:

```
foo = 3
bar = 4
arguments     = ["foo", "bar"]
multiplicator = ->(bind) { arguments.inject(1) { |acc, var| acc * eval(var, bind)} }
multiplicator.call(binding) # => 12
```

---

After more comments two more tries:
simpler:

```
require 'ostruct'
structer = OpenStruct.new
structer.foo = 3
structer.bar = 4
multiplicator = ->() { foo * bar }
structer.define_singleton_method :call_me, &multiplicator
structer.call_me # => 12
```

And more complex one using proxy class to set context properly:

```
class Proxy
  def set_lambda(lambda_object)
    define_singleton_method :run_me, &lambda_object
    return self
  end

  def call(arg_names, *args)
    arg_names.each_with_index do |var, i|
      define_singleton_method var do args[i] end
    end
    self.run_me
  end
end
multiplicator = ->() { foo * bar }
arguments     = [:foo, :bar]
Proxy.new.set_lambda(multiplicator).call(arguments, 3, 4)
```

---

And after lot of comments I believe this is the closest one to OP request:

```
class Proxy
  def set_lambda(lambda_object)
    define_singleton_method :run_me, &lambda_object
    return self
  end

  def set_arguments(args)
    @args_table = args
    return self
  end

  def call(*args)
    @args_table.each_with_index do |var, i|
      define_singleton_method var do args[i] end
    end
    self.run_me
  end
end
multiplicator = ->() { foo * bar }
arguments     = [:foo, :bar]
callable = Proxy.new.set_lambda(multiplicator).set_arguments(arguments)
callable.call(3, 4) # => 12
callable.call(4, 5) # => 20
```

Comment: This is not what I had in mind. I know about `*args/**kwargs`. I actually need the body to contain `foo`/`bar` variables.

Comment: so you want body to refer to local foo and bar variables?

Comment: @ndn please look at provided different solution

Comment: no. I need the body to actually reference arguments called `foo` and `bar`. Imagine the body can not be changed.

Comment: @ndn please look at answer now.

Comment: this is closer to the main idea. A person would want to set the parameter names only once and then be able to `call` it multiple times.

Comment: @ndn I think current version is the closest one

Comment: provides a solution (even though indirect) to the original problem. Appreciate the effort you put into this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to have dynamic arguments

```
 multiplicator = ->(args) { args.inject(:*) }

 multiplicator.call([4,5,6])
 => 120
```

Comment: This is not what I had in mind. I know about `*args/**kwargs`. I actually need the body to contain `foo`/`bar` variables.