# is it possible to use hash keys as a first level variables inside ruby method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'll try to explain myself a little bit more

```
# Lets say I have this hash
options = {a: 1, b: 2}

# and here I'm calling the method
some_method(options)

def some_method(options)
  # now instead of using options[:a] I'd like to simply use a.
  options.delete_nesting_and_create_vars
  a + b # :a + :b also good.
```

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically create a local variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552891/how-to-dynamically-create-a-local-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your options are fixed, like only `:a` and `:b` are the only keys, you can write the method like this:

```
def some_method(a:, b:)
  a + b
end

options = {a: 1, b: 2}

some_method(options) #=> 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible using Ruby2 splat parameters:

```
options = {a: 1, b: 2}

def some_method1(a:, b:)
  a + b
end
```

or:

```
def some_method2(**options)
  options[:a] + options[:b]
end


some_method1 **options
#⇒ 3
some_method2 **options
#⇒ 3
```

Comment: I have not seen usage like first example, can you please explain what is happening in that case, especially what does `a:` really mean in this case.

Comment: @WandMaker these are simple hash-parameters, accepted since Ruby2, but without default values. You should’ve seen `def fun a: 42, b: nil` — that’s the same.

Comment: Thanks, got it now.  Its called [keyword arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments)

Comment: @WandMaker Indeed, I can’t memoize that name for unknown reason :)