# Is there a way to directly access and/or manipulate the `locals` hash from inside of a `partial` Rails ERB template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I am currently splitting some code out to make it more reusable, and other code more succinct.

I realize I am passing a good bit of options into the `locals` hash, besides just the `form` variable, and all of these seem to only apply directly to the input object I am creating.

I was thinking of merging the locals hash into another that contains some defaults, and passing that to the input creation function.

After some researching API docs like these:

- [Ruby on Rails - API - ActionView::Renderer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer_rb.html)
- [Ruby on Rails - API - ActionView::PartialRenderer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer_rb.html)

and digging around to find these last 2 methods in the stack trace:

- `From: .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2/gems/actionpack-3.2.22.5/lib/action_view/template.rb @ line 145 ActionView::Template#render_without_mini_profiler:` ... `2.1.5 (#<ActionView::Template:0x007fa41e138cc8>):0 >`
- `From: .../app/views/shared/_checkbox_group.html.erb @ line 3 ActionView::CompiledTemplates#_app_views_shared__checkbox_group_html_erb___4197967411385159258_70171427980900:` ... `2.1.5 (#<#<Class:0x007fa40f30fec0>:0x007fa40fe71c50>):0 >`

RVM, Ruby, Rails, Formtastic, Pry, Byebug, & Pry-Byebug.

Comment: Mysterious downvote, please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Old, not-so-helpful workaround answer

As it may be convenient from the question's phrasing, one method is to not spend time diving into the Rails template rendering framework code and documentaion, and instead simply provide the options I mentioned for the locals hash, inside of a single property containing a new hash containing them, and pass that into the template.

Later I use that hash to merge with the default hash I had inside of the template and pass that to the input function as normal.

I could leave the Q&A here in case there might still me reasons people would want to directly access the `locals` hash, or could even develop an alternative approach that would be possible as well.

## Update

So I dove into the Rail template rendering framework...

### Exposition

1. I started simply taking this:

```
2.1.5 (#<#<Class:0x007fc01d352e08>:0x007fc018879698>):0 > self.class
=> #<Class:0x007fc01d352e08>
```

2. That wasn't much helpful, then went `up` into `actionpack-3.2.22.5/lib/action_view/template.rb:145` to find this:

```
2.1.5 (#<ActionView::Template:0x007fc011e90510>):0 > method_name
=> "_app_views_shared__adrad_index_html_erb___3381877171036202789_70231455466120"
2.1.5 (#<ActionView::Template:0x007fc011e90510>):0 > view.method(method_name.to_sym)
=> #<Method: #<Class:0x007fc01d352e08>(ActionView::CompiledTemplates)#_app_views_shared__adrad_index_html_erb___3381877171036202789_70231455466120>
2.1.5 (#<ActionView::Template:0x007fc011e90510>):0 > view.method(method_name.to_sym).source_location
=> ["<our project_path>/app/views/shared/some.html.erb", 0]
```

3. Where the last point wasn't great, but then I started looking for `ActionView::CompiledTemplates`, which unfortunately, you cannot use `source_location` to find, or instance variable declarations for that matter (different issue :) ).
4. I decided to randomly search the `actionpack-.../lib/action_view/` directory to find a reference or so in `context.rb`, but instead of looking inside of `template.rb`, I skipped straight to searching for `locals` in that gem's files now.
5. `resolver.rb` did not help much, and neither did `template_renderer.rb`.
6. Once I delved into `template.rb` and found the familiar above stack frame for `render` that my answer had to be between that and my actual page with the included `locals` properties,
7. I followed `compile!` to its definition,
8. saw a familiar `ActionView::CompiledTemplates`,
9. then a `compile`,
10. found an interesting arbitrary, literal, meta source manipulation, as I was sort of expecting with the lack of more stack frames in-between to scour, and the callback-esque naming scheme, I found this curious variable, as a parameter to the dynamically-generated template function: `local_assigns`.
11. I quickly jump around to `locals_code`'s definition since it is also used and verify this is source variable enumeration I was looking for!

**Answer**

`local_assigns`!

Also, I currently don't believe the hash provides any properties I would want to avoid, such as any information specific to only the current partial template page that I wouldn't want to be propagated to the child partial template page.

**Update**

I am starting to do more with this variable, and I wonder if I am limited.
I want to mix-in some default values, which might involve using `binding.local_variable_set`, but it is not able to create new local variables ([How to dynamically create a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552891/how-to-dynamically-create-a-local-variable#18552991)), so I might just have to use my own nested data structure now..