# How to make transform Ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

How can i do transform this array?

```
test = [ 'first_array', '1', '2', '3', 'second_array', '4', '5']
```

Format needed.

```
first_array = ['1', '2', '3']
second_array = ['4' '5']
```

Comment: **Can you clear out the requirements more precisely?** Is this one particular array or its a type or example from a bigger set? Is it always gonna be like first_array, second array a word followed by another word with an underscore in between? what about onethousandtwentyfourtharray? what would be the format? Can there be another word in the array like : [first_array, 1,2,3, second_array, 4,5,6,hello,9,8,you,11,are,cool,13,10,&,1271872]? If you can add some descriptions of requirements and test cases, it would be clearer to answer for all test cases. This would be a good case for test driven p

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to break the array into two parts that can be done using a [slice](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-slice) like this:

```
test = ['first_array', '1', '2', '3', 'second_array', '4', '5']

first_array = test.slice(1, 3)
second_array = test.slice(5, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create the variables from the names taken in the array (e.g. `first_array`, `second_array`), then you should consider using a hash, since you can't dynamically create variables in Ruby.

To accomplish this, you could use `chunk_while` along with `with_object`, for example:

```
test.chunk_while { |_, a| a =~ /^\d+$/ }.with_object({}) { |t, h| h[t.shift] = t }
#=> {"first_array"=>["1", "2", "3"], "second_array"=>["4", "5"]}
```

If you don't care about the names, and want to assign the values manually to different variables, then you can use `map` instead of `with_object` and assign them directly to the variables:

```
first_array, second_array = test.chunk_while { |_, a| a =~ /^\d+$/ }.map { |t| t[1..-1] }

first_array
#=> ["1", "2", "3"]

second_array
# => ["4", "5"]
```

Note that it only will work if the final elements are digits and only two groups are provided, otherwise it will return all groups provided in the initial array, so you will need to wither create a variable for each group or, better yet, just create one variable with the array of arrays:

```
test = [ 'first_array', '1', '2', '3', 'second_array', '4', '5', 'third_array', '7', '8', '9', '10']
arrays = test.chunk_while { |_, a| a =~ /^\d+$/ }.map { |t| t[1..-1] }

arrays
#=> [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5"], ["7", "8", "9", "10"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552991/5101493), since you cannot dynamically create local variables in Ruby, maybe just use a hash.

```
test.chunk_while { |a,b| a[/\d/] && b[/\d/] }
    .each_slice(2)
    .map { |k,v| [*k, v] }
    .to_h

#=> { "first_array" => ["1", "2", "3"], "second_array" => ["4", "5"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby versions 1.9+ one cannot create local variables. An alternative (as suggested by @sagarpandya82), is to create a hash. That could be done as follows.

```
def split_em(arr)
  arr.each_with_object([]) { |o,a| o =~ /\d+/ ? (a.last << o) : a << o << [] }
end

a = split_em(test)
  #=> ["first_array", ["1", "2", "3"], "second_array", ["4", "5"]]
Hash[*a]
  #=> {"first_array"=>["1", "2", "3"], "second_array"=>["4", "5"]}
```

An alternative would be to create instance variables.

```
class Test
  def initialize(*arr)
    split_em(arr).each_slice(2) { |k,v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) }
    end
  end
end

t = Test.new(*test)
  #=> #<Test:0x00000000bcc938 @first_array=["1", "2", "3"], @second_array=["4", "5"]>
t.instance_variables.each { |v| puts "#{v} = #{t.instance_variable_get(v)}" }
@first_array = ["1", "2", "3"]
@second_array = ["4", "5"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable#slice_before`

```
test = ['first_array', '1', '2', '3', 'second_array', '4', '5']

test.slice_before {|e| e.include?("_")}.map {|_,*arr| arr } 
#=> [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5"]]
```