# How to use dynamic variables many times in ruby

Tags: ruby

So I am trying to create dynamic variables, and then use them again later without having to type out the full name. The test code I made is as follows

```
players = [1, 2, 3, 4]

players.each |player|
  instance_variable_set("@player_#{player}_hand", "foo")
  instance_variable_set("@player_#{player}_value", "bar")
}

puts @player_1_hand # => foo
puts @player_3_value # => bar

players.each { |player| 
puts "@player_#{player}_hand" 
}

# => @player_1_hand
# => @player_2_hand
# => @player_3_hand
# => @player_4_hand
```

I want to call and/or update these variables dynamically but I don't know how to do that after I initialize them. The documentation I have found has been more confusing than helpful. Can someone explain how to use these correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552991/5101493

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend that you follow OOP concepts creating a Player object instead of many instance variables, one for each attribute. So, instead of

```
@player_1_hand
@player_3_value
```

Try with a `Player` class

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :number, :hand, :value
  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end
end
```

And then

```
p1 = Player.new(1)
p2 = Player.new(2)
p3 = Player.new(3)
p4 = Player.new(4)
[p1,p2,p3,p4].each do |player|
  player.hand = ...
  player.value = ...
end


p1.hand #=> ...
p1.value #=> ...
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks for wrangling this into proper Ruby form. One thing you can do is make the initializer take hash-style options (*kwargs*), a hash, or employ the `yield self if block_given?` approach to allow quickly populating all those fields.

Comment: You could also have an array of Players instead of discrete variables for each one, and iterate the array with `each`.

Comment: All of those are right approaches, but creating a simple Player class is a good start

Answer (score 2):

I want to warn you that the answer I'm going to give you will work for what you are trying to accomplish, but the way you're going about it is akin to using a wrench when you need a hammer. Sure, the wrench might work, but I'd fire any plumber that didn't use the right tools.

```
players.each { |p| puts instance_variable_get("@player_#{p}_hand") }
```

More about `instance_variable_get` can be found at [apidock](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get).

In general though, you should stay away from instance variables unless you are [creating instances of a class](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/writing_classes/instance_variables.html). But for a script like this, stick with normal variables and stay away from instance variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
players = [1, 2, 3, 4]

players.each { |player|
instance_variable_set("@player_#{player}_hand", "foo")
instance_variable_set("@player_#{player}_value", "bar")
}
```

**To call your variables use eval**

```
players.each { |player| 
puts instance_variable_get("@player_#{player}_hand") 
puts instance_variable_get("@player_#{player}_value")
}
```

**To update your variables use instance_variable_set again**

```
players.each { |player| 
instance_variable_set("@player_#{player}_hand", instance_variable_get("@player_#{player}_hand") + (player + 5).to_s)
puts instance_variable_get("@player_#{player}_hand")
}
```

all that prints:

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo6
foo7
foo8
foo9
```

Comment: How'd you overlook `instance_variable_get`? There's absolutely no reason for using `eval` here. It's massive overkill.

Comment: @tadman it's not about correctness or rubyness here... OP asked a question, specific one, I provided an answer, one that provides a solution. I really don't get your point, obviusly I could uses classes, and all the object stuff super cool, but there is none of those in the OP code, because the code wasn't about object ortiented programming...

Comment: I mean that `eval` is completely out of place here because [`instance_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) exists as a counterpart to `instance_variable_set`. Why not pair these up? That's what they're meant for. If you're using `eval` you better have a really good reason, and there's absolutely no reason here.

Comment: @tadman aaaah I see now, you are right, I modified the answer, you were correct after all, thanks for the patient

Answer (score 1):

When a you want an attr_accessor for every property, a Struct instead of a class will make them for you automatically.

```
Player = Struct.new(:number, :hand, :value)

players = Array.new

(1..4).each do |i|
  player = Player.new(i)
  player.hand = 'something'
  player.value = 'blah'
  players.push player
end

players.each do |player|
  puts "Player #{player.number} has hand #{player.hand} with value #{player.value}"
end
```

Output:

```
Player 1 has hand something with value blah
Player 2 has hand something with value blah
Player 3 has hand something with value blah
Player 4 has hand something with value blah
```