# How to dynamically create local and global variables?

Tags: ruby

```
{"string_1_0" => "1.0","$string_1"=>2}
puts $string_1
```

1. In the above  mentioned the ruby hash, now i want to turn hash key into local variable.
2. Use  hash key string as it is to turn into local variable.
3. it should run with ruby instead of jruby
4. Expected output:

```
2
```

Comment: This is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552891/how-to-dynamically-create-a-local-variable

Comment: Why is your question tagged as `ruby-on-rails`? What does it have to do with rails? Are you hoping to access these variables in a rails view, or is the fact that you're using rails irrelevant?

Comment: Likewise for `rubygems` -- What does your question have to do with 3rd party ruby libraries?

Comment: Why are you using a version of Rails that hasn't been maintained for years, and has numerous unpatched security holes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define a local variable with a full stop (`.`) character in ruby. That is not valid syntax.

```
(eval):2: unexpected fraction part after numeric literal
string_1.0 = "1.0"
```

Additionally, you cannot dynamically define local variables. There are [various workarounds to sort-of achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18552891/1954610), however, fundamentally I think [you are asking an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

For example, have you considered using an `OpenStruct`, or passing this hash as `locales` when rendering a template, or instead dynamically setting **instance** variables?

Answer (score 0):

As Tom stated above, you appear to be asking an XY problem and could likely solve the fundamental/core problem in a much more efficient manner. More detail as to exactly *what* you're trying to accomplish and *why* you feel the need to convert a `key:value` to a local variable would be helpful.

That being said, there are a lot of potential alternatives but most would require that you deal with your naming syntax first.  As Tom stated above, you cannot include a dot in variable names.  Once that issue was dealt with, the closest thing I can think of to what you're asking for would be to define a `method` instead of a local variable.  That might look something like this:

```
hash = {"string_1_0" => "1,0", "string_2_2" => "2,2"}
hash.each {|key, value| define_method (key) {value}}
    
string_1_0  #=> 1,0
string_2_2  #=> 2,2
```

Again, just beware that these are `methods` and *not* local variables.  As such, they will be accessible on a much more global scale which may or may not work for your application.

Comment: You don't need to use `eval` to define a method! Use `define_method`.

Comment: You are correct good sir.  I edited my answer.

Comment: How can i do it for local and global variables like {"$string_2" => 2,"string_1_0"=>"1.0"}

Comment: Here's another alternative:  
```hash = {"$string_1_0" => "1,0", "string_2_2" => "2,2"}
hash.each {|key, value| eval "#{key} = \"#{value}\""}```
Using ```eval``` is typically considered bad practice most of the time and many people insist that its always bad practice.  I know from personal experience though that it does have its applications, so bad practice or not, its good to know that its an available approach.  Just read up on using it though so you're at least aware of the risks.