# assigning values of array into variables in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, variables

I am trying to assign the each value of an array into different variables. But I am getting error as "Expecting end."

```
strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
strs.each_with_index do |x, i|
"b#{i}" = x
end
```

what is going wrong here ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically create a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552891/how-to-dynamically-create-a-local-variable)

Comment: How long could your array possibly be?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is like saying

```
"howdy" = 1
```

You can't say that. That expression attempts to assign into a string literal. You can't do that. A string literal is not an lvalue (a thing that can go on the left side of an equal sign).

If you are trying to say "make a variable called `howdy` and assign this value to it", you can't do that because local variables cannot be created on the fly. See [How to dynamically create a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552891/how-to-dynamically-create-a-local-variable).

However, the real core of your issue is that you should not even *want* to do what you're doing. You already have an array, a wonderful thing that allows you to reference each entry by number. `"flower"` in your code is already `strs[0]`, and so on. The whole point of the array is that it lets you do that. There is thus no need for individual variables with number names; the array *is* the variable with number names.

Comment: @engineersmnky "the way I read this is OP knows the object and wants the index" I don't read it like that at all. What I see is the OP trying to form variables `b0`, `b1`, and `b2` on the fly and assign them the values from the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to WHY you are attempting to create local variables when you already sort of have them.  Consider the following where we simply replace your suggested `b0` with `b[0]`:

```
strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
b = strs
b[0]  #=>  "flower"
```

You could optionally convert your array to a hash using an approach similar to what you've already tried and replace `b0` with `b[0]`:

```
b = {}
strs.each_with_index do |x, i|
  b[i] = x
end

b[0]  #=>  "flower"
```

Or even something like this:

```
my_variables = {}
strs.each_with_index do |x, i|
  my_variables[:"b#{i}"] = x
end

my_variables[:b0] #=>  "flower"
```