# How to define dynamic variable and assign it to some value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic-variables

I want to create dynamic `variable` and assign values to them. Here is quick sample what I tried so far.

```
array = %w(this is a test)
array.each_with_index do |c,v|
  puts "variable_#{v}".to_sym
end
```

which gives me output like this:

```
# variable_0
# variable_1
# variable_2
# variable_3
```

But when I am trying to assign value like below:

```
array.each_with_index do |c,v|
  puts "variable_#{v}".to_sym = 45 # I want to assign value which will be result of api, here I just pass 45 static
end
```

this gives me an error:

> undefined method `to_sym=' for "variable_0":String (NoMethodError)

If I removed `.to_sym` it gives me an error like:

> syntax error, unexpected '='

Please help me. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

**Note:** This is just a sample code to understand how to create dynamic variables and assign them variable. In my app it's a instance_variable and I want to use them to achieve my goal.

Comment: Have you considered using a Hash? You could have an Instance Hash and assign to it any value you like with dynamic key names.

Comment: I wanted to loop with these variable, so I think Can I do it using hash key?

Comment: You can't do that without initializing that variable outside that block. Because otherwise it will not be accessible outside of that block. You should use enumerator to save result list.

Comment: @Anuja : Can you show some example? I appreciate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set local variables in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963678/dynamically-set-local-variables-in-ruby)

Comment: Your code seems to be setting local variables (e.g. `foo`), but your note says you want to set an instance variable (e.g. `@foo`).  I'm not sure what it is you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you really need to set instance variable dynamically, `instance_variable_set` may help you.

```
array.each_with_index do |c,v|
  instance_variable_set "@variable_#{v}".to_sym, 45 # `@` indicates instance variable
end
```

Comment: 'undefined method `to_sym=' for "@variable_0":String (NoMethodError)'

Comment: Thanks for your solution but then I realized it will become more complicated so I plan to make new function and pass dynamic name of variable.. anyways thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can collect result in array or hash. Its difficult to give example with partial info. But in array you can collect result as follows:

```
result_set = array.collect do |c|
  45
end
```

Which will give you

```
result_set = ["this", "is", "a", "test"]
```

For hash let me know what type of key and value you want to collect so that I can give you particular example.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but then I realized it will become more complicated so I plan to make new function and pass dynamic name of variable.. anyways thanks

Comment: Welcome. But I didn't get the actual requirement. I hope you got solution for your problem.