# Ruby create n numbers of arrays with name array1, array2

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I have been scouring the internet for an answer and can't seem to make it work. I'm pretty new using Ruby so please be patient. I am trying to write a program that asks user to choose how many arrays they want to create and that automatically create and name these arrays.

Here's what I have so far, please assume that the user will just input an integer. So if the user types 3 it will create myArray1, myArray2, myArray3

```
puts 'how many arrays do you want to create?'
number_of_arrays = gets.chomp.to_i

(1..number_of_arrays).each do |i|
  myArray+"#{i}" = Array.new 
end
```

I am aware that **myArray+"#{i}" = Array.new** doesn't work but I am trying to find a way to do that, any suggestions and help is welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: Make an array of arrays. It may be possible to dynamically create local variables using reflection, but it's definitely not what you *want* to do. For instance, how would you know which variables are "safe" to refer to if you don't know which variables exist?

Comment: Follow @Silvio's advice. Since v1.8 it has not been possible to create local variables dynamically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically set local variables in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28767601/895789)

Comment: I agree with all previous commenters - this is a terrible idea. My suggestion is to put the arrays in a Hash, something like `arrays = {"array1" => [1,2,3],  "array2" => [4,5,6] }`. Easy to construct, iterate, pinpoint the one you want, contained etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create variables dynamically in ruby. But you can use an hash.

```rb
puts 'how many arrays do you want to create?'
number_of_arrays = gets.chomp.to_i
array_of_arrays = {}

number_of_arrays.times do |i|
  array_of_arrays["array#{i+1}".to_sym] = []
end
```

That will return an hash that will look like that:

```rb
{:array1=>[], :array2=>[], :array3=>[], :array4=>[], :array5=>[]}
```